# How do I install phpMyAdmin on Fedora 20 using the remi repository?

Tags: software-installation, yum, phpmyadmin

I needed to install LAMP on my Fedora 20 32-bit. Everything was fine until I had to install phpMyAdmin.

This is basically the same question as this question: [install phpmyadmin in fedora 20 - ask.fedoraproject.org](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/55493/install-phpmyadmin-in-fedora-20/).

I tried to follow this [tutorial](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/lamp-linux-apache-mysql-php-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/#install_mysql_mariadb),  but got the same errors as one of commenters. One of the answers says to uninstall what we installed with the "remi" repo. But that's a going to be a pain, since I have to go through the tutorial backwards and hope `yum remove package` will work.

Does anybody have better advice? Or can you confirm what the user is saying in the tutorial? Do you have any tips/tricks to make it easier or stuff to not do?

#### Edit: command & errors

```
$ sudo yum --enablerepo=remi install phpmyadmin
```

This gives me the following errors:

> Error: Package: php-recode-5.5.18-1.fc20.remi.i686 (remi)
>              Requires: php-common(x86-32) = 5.5.18-1.fc20.remi
>              Installed: php-common-5.6.0-1.fc20.remi.i686 (@remi-php56)
>                  php-common(x86-32) = 5.6.0-1.fc20.remi
>              Available: php-common-5.5.6-1.fc20.i686 (fedora)
>                  php-common(x86-32) = 5.5.6-1.fc20
>              Available: php-common-5.5.17-2.fc20.i686 (updates)
>                  php-common(x86-32) = 5.5.17-2.fc20
>              Available: php-common-5.5.17-2.fc20.remi.i686 (remi)
>                  php-common(x86-32) = 5.5.17-2.fc20.remi
>              Available: php-common-5.5.18-1.fc20.remi.i686 (remi)
>                  php-common(x86-32) = 5.5.18-1.fc20.remi
>
> Error: Package: php-bcmath-5.5.18-1.fc20.remi.i686 (remi)
>              Requires: php-common(x86-32) = 5.5.18-1.fc20.remi
>              Installed: php-common-5.6.0-1.fc20.remi.i686 (@remi-php56)
>                  php-common(x86-32) = 5.6.0-1.fc20.remi
>              Available: php-common-5.5.6-1.fc20.i686 (fedora)
>                  php-common(x86-32) = 5.5.6-1.fc20
>              Available: php-common-5.5.17-2.fc20.i686 (updates)
>                  php-common(x86-32) = 5.5.17-2.fc20
>              Available: php-common-5.5.17-2.fc20.remi.i686 (remi)
>                  php-common(x86-32) = 5.5.17-2.fc20.remi
>              Available: php-common-5.5.18-1.fc20.remi.i686 (remi)
>                  php-common(x86-32) = 5.5.18-1.fc20.remi

**NOTE:** There are two others like this.

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to fix this problem. Wasn't has difficult as I thought !
The guy at fedora was right.

sideburns said, responding to the question (first link on my question):

> From what you've written, you installed both packages from a third-party repo instead of using the ones from the standard Fedora repo. If so, remove them, remove the repo they came from and then install the Fedora versions as that will bring in all of the needed dependencies. Once you have that done, we can worry about php.

So I executed these commands one after the other:

`yum remove php` 
`yum remove php-common`
`yum remove mysql`
`yum remove httpd`

This got me back to were I started. Then I followed this tutorial to reinstall everything: [Tutorial](http://amidstsky.com/apache-php-mysql-phpmyadmin-fedora/)